# C# Excel Formatting Issue

Tags: c#, excel, interop

I have an issue which I cannot solve. I'm writing some strings into Excel cells. But Excel is formatting them in a wrong way. These strings are IDs, for example 12A1, 12D1, 12E1 etc..
Everything works well except from the "12E1" string which is seen as an exponential. I tried with numberformat but it doesn't work.

For example the string "12E3" is written as 1.2e03, or 1200 and so on. i just want to see "12E3" written there. This program is going to be used by many PCs so i cannot change the Microsoft Excel General Settings for everyone!

Thank you and sorry for my poor english!

EDIT: Here's the code:

```
foreach (var Citem in ComQuery)
{
    i++;
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, 1] = "'" + Citem.commessaID; //the item is "12D3"
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, 2] = Citem.commessaID;       //the item is "12D3"
}
```

The first cell gives me the string "12D3" but with a warning on Excel, the second cell gives me 1.2E+004

Comment: And now you will show us some code will you?:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
var id = "12E1"
ws.Range("A1").Value = "'" + id
```

which will give your cell the following value:

`'12E1`

Comment: This can help, thanks. But in case i need to re-use the data, will i need to get rid of the "'" char?

Comment: Yes, you will. You could have WriteID() and ReadID() utilities that add and remove the extra character.

Comment: @PatMustard, not necessary you will need to get rid of "'" while reading from cell. In Excel "'" is a kind of conversion (cast) sign to text. When checking `Cell.Value` it's omitted. Check it.

Comment: @KazJaw you were right! The "'" char is omitted without any manual disgard! Thanks to both of you, now it works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

```
xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, 2].NumberFormat = "@";
xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, 2] = Citem.commessaID;
```